# How to set / read shell variables in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, pytest, exit-code

I'm teaching myself Jenkins and am trying to direct execution flow of a '*pipeline job via declarative syntax*' based on result of Test Stage, which I try to implement via the pytest exit code into a shell variable (*i.e. if success then send success email and deploy, if failure then send failure email and exit script..*)

This works for me when I export if I set a new shell variable in the CLI. It also seems to work in this Jenkins script to the point when I receive the pytest exit code and assign it to my shell variable. However after this, when I try to read the shell variable I've just set, it seems to have a null value. Any ideas?

```
stage('Test') {
    steps {
        sh 'export pytestExitCode'
        sh 'echo "pytestExitCode before being assigned the pytest exit code is: "$pytestExitCode'
        sh 'pytest'
        sh 'echo "Pytest completed with exit code: "$?'
        sh 'pytestExitCode=$?'
        sh 'echo $pytestExitCode'
        sh 'echo "pytestExitCode after being assigned the pytest exit code is: "$pytestExitCode'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins runs each `sh` step in a new shell session. Thus, exported variables will only be valid inside the script you define as parameter for the `sh` step.

For example:

```
sh 'export variable=value'
sh 'echo "variable: $variable"'
```

will output

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ export 'variable=value'
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo 'variable: '
variable:
```

---

If you only need the variables inside the shell script, you can combine the `sh` steps into a single `sh` step. Note that Jenkins uses `-xe` shell flags by default so the script execution will stop on first non-zero exit code. See [steps reference](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) for details.

For example:

```
sh '''
    export variable=value
    echo "variable: $variable"
'''
```

will output

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ export 'variable=value'
+ echo 'variable: value'
variable: value
```

---

If you need the value in other steps, you could use groovy variables instead. For those you could use `returnStatus` or `returnStdout` parameters of the `sh` step. See [steps reference](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) for details.

For example:

```
script {
    exitCode = sh returnStatus: true, script: 'exit 3'
}
echo "$exitCode"
```

will output

```
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ exit 3
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] echo
3
```

---

Finally, for executing step conditionally based on stage success or failure, see also the `success` and `failure` blocks provided by the pipeline or stage [`post` sections](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post).

Jenkins also marks stage as failed if shell script fails (i.e., returns with non-zero exit code) and skips stages following the failed stage. Thus, there is usually no need to manually check the exit code.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, @kangasta. It' has been a great help. cheers!