# How to make jenkins persist with custom modified global variable in the post notification channels like Slack or Email?

Tags: jenkins, slack

How to make Jenkins persist with custom modified global variables in the post notification channels like Slack or Email?

We have a Jenkins job in which we have created a custom global variable using Inject environment variables settings say FX_URL="www.gmail.com" to some temporary/arbitrary/random url.

We are modifying this variable in the shell script build step and want the modified value to be used in the Slack notification channel.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$FX_URL"
#Some new URL from one other operation"
FX_URL="www.yahoo.com"
echo $FX_URL
```

This modified variable value is persisting till this shell script build step only and in Slack post notification channel original value/URL is coming instead of the modified URL of what we desired.

So how can make Jenkins persist with custom modified global variables in the post notification channel like Slack?

Comment: Each `sh` step is executed in a new shell session and thus the variables set there are only valid inside the script passed in as the parameter. Maybe groovy variable would work, if you are using pipeline job: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76696543/how-to-set-read-shell-variables-in-jenkins/76699831#76699831